# InvalidCastException on nullable enum

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var value = (MyEnum?)cboList.SelectedValue;
var required = value.GetValueOrDefault() == MyEnum.SomeValue;
```

`cboList` is a ComboBox.

I am getting an `InvalidCastException` on the second line. Why is this?

Comment: What's `cboList`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m8kmnv)). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Another question: if you pop that in a debugger, what's `cboList.SelectedValue` at the time of the cast? Because my guess is that it's something that can't be cast to a `MyEnum?`. If `SelectedValue` is an `object`, that might be one of those "unboxing to the wrong type" situation.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue was set to DBNull. Handling it solves the problem.

Comment: However, the interesting question is: Why do you get an `InvalidCastException` in the **second** line? Shouldn't the cast to `MyEnum?` in the **first** line fail?

Comment: @Heinzi line number could be off by 1?

Comment: @TanveerBadar Yes it's always off by 1. Always. No matter how the code looks like. That's why I couldn't figure out immediately what was wrong.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Make sense. Accept your own answer and close this question.